# Storing AVDepthData for processing in Swift

Tags: swift, video-processing, pose-detection

I'm trying to use `VNDetectHumanBodyPose3DRequest` to get 3D keypoints from videos taken in my app at 30 fps. Since the request takes too long to do in real time I'm saving the `CMSampleBuffer`s from the camera to a video file using an `AVAssetWriter`. I'm then processing the frames after the recording. I'm trying to get better results by incorporating `AVDepthData` for each frame into the request but I'm not sure how to store the depth data to process them after recording.

I can't store the depth data into an array since it takes too much memory. I also tried using `CGImageDestination` to save each frame as an HEIC file with the depth data encoded but saving each frame is too slow. I'm thinking I could encode each `AVDepthData` as a frame in a separate video and then convert each frame back but I'm not sure how I could do this. Does anyone know of a way to go about this or have any resources to point me towards? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I can can write the depthMap in each `AVDepthData` to a file on disk using `Data` and `FileManager`. Then after recording I read the data from the file and create dictionaries as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avdepthdata/creating_auxiliary_depth_data_manually), and recreate the `AVDepthData` by passing the dictionary into its initializer.